# Math on currency/strings with dollar signs

Tags: javascript, math, currency

Is it possible to have a string, like `$10.50` and do math on it within javascript? I can't find an answer on this site.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/QkCyM/2/)

HTML:

```
<p id="cost">$10.50</p>
---
<div id="output"></div>
```

​
JavaScript:

```
$('#output').html($('#cost').html() / 2);​
```

Output:

```
NaN
```

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker I have tried exactly what is in my JSFIDDLE link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do math on it **if** you strip away the dollar sign using; since it's usually at the first position, you can simply use `.substring(1)` on the string value.

```
$('#output').html($('#cost').html().substring(1) / 2);​
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<p id="cost" data-value="1050" data-currency="$">$10.50</p>
---
<div id="output"></div>


var el = $("#cost");
$('#output').html( el.data("currency") + (el.data("value") / 2 / 100));​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QkCyM/5/

​

Answer (score 0):

No, but why not keep the '$' separate:

```
<p>$<span id="cost">10.50</span></p>
```

or you have to parse the string and strip the '$"

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot do maths on strings. If you do it, JavaScript will try implicit type conversion, but it fails for strings not beginning with digits - resulting in `NaN`.

First, strip of the dollar sign (e.g. by [`.slice(1)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)), then use [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) to get a number. Now do your division, and then use [`.toFixed(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) for converting it back to a string to output. Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QkCyM/7/.

And don't forget [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/).